# How to compare indexes of two li having different ul in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

i have this function written and i want to comapare both li by indexes and then perform some action on one li
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbCbv.png)
html code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwKdn.png)

Comment: can you not just add a class to each and use that as a target?

Comment: paste your code here man. not images

Comment: alert($('#node1').index());
        $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".btn").click(function(){
          if($("#node1").index()== $("#li1").index())
       
              {alert("yesss");}
              else{alert("no");}
              
         });
        }); here is the code bro,i tried classes too,but that did not work,help me out please

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code.  It uses jQuery .each with taking the index, then uses .eq() to get the correct corresponding element index.  THen it compares them.  I'm not super sure what your goal, just leave a comment if you need more help.

```
<ul id="allItems">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="dropDiv">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$("#allItems li").each(function (index) {
    firstLi = $(this);
    secondLi = $("#dropDiv li").eq(index);

    if (firstLi.html() === secondLi.html()) {
        console.log("same "  + firstLi.html());
    } else {
        console.log("different "  + firstLi.html() + " second: " + secondLi.html());
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: i tried your code but it says they are different in alert but they have same indexes why it says different everytime?? please help me

Comment: Updated the code, this should work now.  Note, only 2 of your li's match...  it will print whether or not they are the same, and their values

Comment: thats Great,Thankyou so much,what if i want to match 1st li of #allitems to the all li of #dropdiv and on same index it will become green and on different index they become red.is it possible ?reply as soon as possible,i need to get it done by tonight.Thanks